# remove header row from csv javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, csv, header

I need to remove the header file from a csv file being read into MaxMSP using javascript. I have tried out various functions but I cannot find the solution. Anyone can help me out? Here is my code until now (it reads a csv file and converts the symbols into floats and then outputs it to maxmsp). in the link you can find a sample csv. https://www.dropbox.com/s/fe8nx1bcqe2k19r/shorttable.csv

```
function import(filename)
{
    var f = new File(filename);

    if (f.open) {
        var i = 0;
        outlet(0, "clear");

        while (f.position < f.eof) {
            var str = f.readline(); 
            var a = str.split(","); // conver strings to array (elements are delimited by a coma)
            // a[5] /= 1000; // uncomment to devide the 6th column by 1000
            var date = a[0] 
            var open = parseFloat(a[1]);
            var high = parseFloat(a[2]);
            var low = parseFloat(a[3]);
            var close = parseFloat(a[4]);
            var volume = parseFloat(a[5]);
            var adjusted_close = parseFloat(a[6]);
            outlet(0, i++, date,open,high,low,close,volume,adjusted_close); // store in the coll        
        }
        f.close();
    } else {
        error("couldn't find the file ("+ filename +")\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: A 'f.readline()' statement before the while loop will skip the first line.

Comment: So easy yet I had trouble finding it. Can I ask an additional question then: I want to reverse the contents of the file after removing that header line. However, I always get errors saying that f.reverse(); is not a function. What is the right command then to reverse it?

Also: should I do the reverse operation in the loop or before? I would think before as only afterwards I want to have index numbers (i++) and parseFloat but maybe I am wrong.

Comment: First, I promotied the comment to the answers.

Comment: You want to reverse the contents of the line or the entire file?

Comment: The entire file. So were the original is 
2014-02-21,25.12,25.19,24.94,24.94,37146000,24.94
2014-02-20,25.31,25.32,25.02,25.12,32274900,25.12
2014-02-19,25.68,25.77,25.37,25.40,33893100,25.18

The output is:
2014-02-19,25.68,25.77,25.37,25.40,33893100,25.18
2014-02-20,25.31,25.32,25.02,25.12,32274900,25.12
2014-02-21,25.12,25.19,24.94,24.94,37146000,24.94

Comment: Well, then a simple way would be to keep storing the lines in an array and then process them in the reverse order.

Comment: so how do I do that? The strings are converted to arrays. I suppose after that statement (and before the parsings) I should put something but what?

Comment: var lines = text.split("\n");

and then,

lines.reverse()

Comment: Reverse does this: from one entry in an array at index 1, [a, b, c] it makes [c, b, a]. I have a multi-entry array so (simplified) 1)[date, float, float] 2) [date, float, float] and so on. I want to sort on the date, the first item in the array. The file just needs to be read from the last to the first. Is there no command for that?

Comment: Not sure if you can read a file itself from the last, but what I am suggesting you to do is, reading the entire file; break it into lines and feed that in the array 'lines'; and when you use lines.reverse() you have what you wanted to achieve.

Comment: Where should I put those commands? I am stuck in where I should put them. Would it be possible to make the while condition reversed someway so it goes down somehow?

Comment: Can you post a separate question for this part? I'll post an answer there.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22025256/reverse-a-csv-file
here you go.

Answer (score 0):

A 'f.readline()' statement before the while loop will skip the first line.