# Reverse a csv file

Tags: javascript, csv

I have a csv file being imported in MaxMSP and sent through a javascript object. The following operation take place:
1) header line is removed from the file
2) csv file transformed in array 
3) elements from array are transformed in floats (date as well)
4) index number is put in front of every line (as the coll object in MaxMSP needs an index number)
What I am missing is that the csv file is antichronological. I need to get the data chronological. The most logical would be to read the file backwards line by line (after the header is removed). Link to [app](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/arko0s219v50yyu/lcgEuaDhu0) and [csvfile](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fe8nx1bcqe2k19r/shorttable.csv)
You can doubleclick on the js object to see the code. After you have dropped a csv file on the hotspot, you can doubleclick on the coll object to see the contents.

Here goes the code:

```
    function import(filename)
{
    var f = new File(filename); 
    if (f.open) {
        var i = 0;
        outlet(0, "clear");
        f.readline();


        while (f.position < f.eof)
        {
            var str = f.readline(); 


            var a = str.split(","); // convert strings to array (elements are delimited by a coma)
            // a[5] /= 1000; // uncomment to divide the 6th column by 1000      


            var date = Date.parse(a[0]);
            var date = parseFloat(date);
            var open = parseFloat(a[1]);
            var high = parseFloat(a[2]);
            var low = parseFloat(a[3]);
            var close = parseFloat(a[4]);
            var volume = parseFloat(a[5]);
            var adjusted_close = parseFloat(a[6]);


      outlet(0, i++, date,open,high,low,close,volume,adjusted_close); // store in the coll        
        }
        f.close();
    } else {
        error("couldn't find the file ("+ filename +")\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: just .reverse() the array you already have.

Comment: Please copy the code formatted in here. External links will die soon and not everyone likes to (or is allowed to, if at a work place) download files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to do that:

```
function import(filename)
{
    var f = new File(filename);
    var csv = [];

    if (f.open) {
        var str = f.readline(); //Skips first line.
        while (f.position < f.eof) {
            var str = f.readline(); 
            csv.push(str);
        }
        f.close();
    } else {
        error("couldn't find the file ("+ filename +")\n");
    }

    //Now you may do whatever you want with each line in the array
    for (var i=(csv.length-1); i>=0; i--) {
        alert(csv[i]);
        //Yes, now you may parse contents of each line in the csv file
    }
```

Comment: Probably I should stop for today but I want to finish it. Shouldn't I put a var i =0; in the beginning for the indexnumber later on? The condition for each (var line in csv) is that correct? Where do you get the variable line? Where you say parse it, I just have to  put all parseFloat commands is that correct?

Comment: I changed it to the format you expected. In retrospect using for..in was not a good idea anyway. Yes, inside the loop you do you parseFloat or whatever is there in the csv file.

Comment: I think I am almost there. I get an error that alert is not defined. How should I solve that?

Comment: alert was only was demo on how to use the line :D. You can remove it.

Comment: I am getting crashes. I put after your comment all parse commands and the outlet command.
  var adjusted_close = parseFloat(a[6]);
  outlet(0, i++, date,open,high,low,close,volume,adjusted_close);

Comment: Ok, so I can parse the data but only one line. When I want to do var str = csv.readline(); it tells me that csv.readline is not a function. I do not really understand what the name should be for the temporary array you constructed.

Comment: I have f.readline in my code. To use csv.readline, csv should be a file object.

Comment: I am really not getting it. What should I write after the for-condition?  var str = f.readline();
                var a = str.split(",");
and then all parse commands, which results is "str is null". Just var a = str.split(","); and all parse commands results in one line (the last line which has become the first now) being output for all lines ( so all lines are the same). So I need some kind of statement before defining var a. THe questions: which one?
I also added var x = 0; and then for the output x++ otherwise if using i++ I was getting crashes.

Comment: @ Gat: thank you so much for your help. `var str = csv.join("\n");
   var a = csv[i].split(",");` did the trick. I am getting my data in chronological order, without a header, with an index number. For now I am not using the division by thousand (maybe I will do that later). It is a bit slow when loading big csvfiles (over 2000 entries) but I suppose that is normal for Javscript right? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Awesome! Glad it worked. Yes, JS would be slow for larger CSV files.